# How do I avoid being insta-gibbed by the hammer?

Tags: loadout

In capture-the-hammer mode, I am having trouble dodging the hammer.

Moving sideways does not seem to work because the hammercarrier automatically and instantly adjusts when he attacks.

Aside from keeping a safe distance away, is there a better strategy for close combat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding the hammer is pretty straightforward.

You need to focus your view on the hammercarrier and predict his next attack which will most likely start when he is in range. At that moment you just need to do a dive roll in the opposite direction (since you focus him with your view/weapon this should be rolling backwards).

Rolling backwards makes sure that the hammer will not hit.

However you will need good map-awareness/knowledge to prevent diving into a wall or off a cliff.

Furthermore increasing your speed with juice helps too.

Comment: It seems to me that you can dive straight through the hammercarrier as well since he cannot turn 180° at once (seems more like 70° in each direction). I need to do more testing to confirm this though.